# Как изменить название кнопки в классе dialog при нажатии на кнопку в классе mainwindow

Tags: qt

я около месяца как начал изучать QT, то есть новичок.
Собственно дело в следующем, создал новый проект (Приложение -> qt widgets), чтобы опробовать встроенный конструктор форм

собственно есть 2 формы mainwindow.ui и dialog.ui на каждую из них в конструкторе я положил по одному pushButton

1) mainwindow.ui название кнопки - MainButton

2) dialog.ui название кнопки - DialogButton

Так вот, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии pushButton в mainwindow изменялось название pushButton в dialog

И что важно: мне нужно всё это сделать через сигналы и слоты. Собственно искал в поисковиках и книгах, но видимо плохо искал и не нашёл как через connect передавать сигналы между классами.

Выложу код приложения, если есть возможность допишите его как там чего с сигналами и слотами, чтобы я потом разбирался что там к чему.

код dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

Код dialog.cpp

```
include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Код mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Код mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Код main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Dialog dialogwindow;
    dialogwindow.show();
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `connect` имеет следующую сигнатуру:

```
 static QMetaObject::Connection connect(const QObject *sender, const QMetaMethod &signal,
                    const QObject *receiver, const QMetaMethod &method,
                    Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection);
```

следовательно вам нужно получить из `MainWindow` указатель на объект который будет посылать сигнал(кнопка) и сам сигнал (`QPushButton::pressed`) для этого пишете фунции:

```
 QMetaMethod MainWindow::getSignal()
 {
     return QMetaMethod::fromSignal(&QPushButton::pressed);
 }

 const QObject* MainWindow::getSender()
 {
    return  ui.button;
 }
```

аналогично пишете функции у `Dialog` и получаете примерно такое:

```
const QObject* sender = w.getSender();
QMetaMethod signal = w.getSignal();

const QObject* receiver= dialogwindow.getReseiver();
QMetaMethod slot= dialogwindow.getSlot();

w.connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot );

dialogwindow.show();
w.show();    
return a.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog (добавляем слот для получения строки):

```
class Dialog : public QDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void setText(const QString& text) {
        ui->pushButton->setText(text);
    }
}
```

MainWindow (добавляем сигнал с текстом, который эмиттрируется по нажатию на кнопку):

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent):
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]{
            emit textChanged(<Какой-то текст, например из QLineEdit>);
        });
    }

signals:
    void textChanged(const QString& text);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Dialog dialogwindow;

    // Соединяем сигнал, с текстом из главного окна,
    // со слотом диалога
    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::textChanged, 
                     &dialogwindow, &Dialog::setText);

    dialogwindow.show();
    w.show();    
    return a.exec();
}
```